# Syntax - 424 Object Required Error on Line of Code

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, syntax

I keep getting a 424: Object Reuqired error on the following line of code:

```
 If rstCurrent.Fields(1).Value Is Not Null Then
 MaxDate = rstCurrent.Fields(1)
 End If
```

Is the syntax for this an issue. Why would it pick up the line before it:

```
If rstCurrent.Fields.Count > 0 Then

End if
```

and give me the correct number of feilds for the table (8) but error out on the previous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VBA syntax:

```vb
If Not IsNull(rstCurrent.Fields(1).Value) Then
    MaxDate = rstCurrent.Fields(1).Value
End If
```